# Write the charge of an ion as an apex outside the square brackets with chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I have the structure of the nitrate ion written down in chemfig and I'd like to add its charge as an apex outside the square brackets (see below). Is there a correct way to do it or do I just `\raisebox` a minus sign?

It should look like this:
[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\[\schemestart\chemleft[
\chemfig{\lewis{246,O}-[:30]N(-[@{leg}:90]@{Oss}\lewis{024,O})-[:-30]\lewis{026,O}}\chemright]
\chemmove{\draw[->]($(Oss)+(0:2.5mm)$).. controls +(-10:2mm) and +(10:3mm).. ($(leg)+(0:.5mm)$);}
\schemestop\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Counter ions and charge of a complex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462238/134144)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compounds inside `\schemestart` and `\schemestop` are tikz nodes with names you can refer to. `chemfig` names them `c1`, `c2`, … but you can also give them own names. You can use this in `\chemdraw` to place the minus:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \schemestart
    \chemleft[
      \chemfig{\lewis{246,O}-[:30]N(-[@{leg}:90]@{Oss}\lewis{024,O})-[:-30]\lewis{026,O}}
    \chemright]
  \schemestop
  \chemmove{
    \draw[->]
      ($(Oss)+(0:2.5mm)$)
      .. controls +(-10:2mm) and +(10:3mm)..
      ($(leg)+(0:.5mm)$);
    \node[xshift=5pt] at (c1.north east) {$-$} ;
  }
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]