# Counter ions and charge of a complex

Tags: chemfig

how can I add the charge and the counter ions to my complex?
I'm using chemfig.

```
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemleft[\chemfig{Ni
(<:[1]OH_2)
(-[2]OH_2)
(<:[3]OH_2)
(<[5]OH_2)
(-[6]OH_2)
(<[7]OH_2)
}\chemright]}{\ce{[Ni(OH2)6]Cl2}}
\schemestop
```

[image: example missing counter ions and charge]

Thanks!

Comment: `\chemfig` works in math mode as well, so just `$\chemleft[...\chemright]^{2+}$ \chemfig{Cl^{-}}` inside `\chemname` should do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is no need to explicitly use math environment. Also, I slightly adjusted ligand orientation and geometry:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\chemname{
    \chemleft{[}
        \chemfig{
            Ni
            (<:[:30]OH_2)
            (-[:90]OH_2)
            (<:[:150]H_2O)
            (<[:-150]H_2O)
            (-[:-90]OH_2)
            (<[:-30]OH_2)
        }
    \chemright{]^{2+}}
    \ce{2 Cl-}
}{\ce{[Ni(OH2)6]Cl2}}

\end{document}
```