# How to draw coordination complexes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, chemfig, chemistry

I am in need of drawing chemical complexes in space, with octahedral or tetrahedral or square or any other structure (for instance `[Co(SO_4)(NH_3)_5]^+`). Would anyone have any suggestion about which package to go to ? My inclination would be tikz but would there be some more specific package ? I don't think chemfig would be suited for that... ?

Thanks and have a great day !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counter ions and charge of a complex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462238/counter-ions-and-charge-of-a-complex)

Comment: Also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78275/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers ! Actually, it is useful but it is not quite what I was looking for. Sorry, my fault : I am looking for a way to produce figures such as this one : https://files.mtstatic.com/site_4334/18479/0?Expires=1614076506&Signature=WyOdnmiCsw8BOVr00WL5NsHkTQmmQmVWm8x2DuAfP0QuJ0XZsPe2t8v~J2SVAXERdBWK9OfmDuoogo~T9uXeflGGyFy~z3vKSU3POS2ESZ7VqOQ8HZfzuIW9HO6lIvneETKTySQOdKhzWtuCY5pu24EoJI0tob2fLm-6F8h6ojA_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJ5Y6AV4GI7A555NA